# How to change screen brightness on a Lenovo E46A?

Tags: 11.10, brightness

I am using lenovo E46A in window i was able to change screen brightness with the control (Fn) but now in ubuntu I can't change it the cursor shows but brightness doesn't change a bit ....So someone please help me .

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to system settings and click on screen.

Comment: Doesn't work this way..Don't know why ! !